# Remove multiple items and remove all items from ListView ObserverCollection

Tags: wpf, listview, c#-4.0, listviewitem

I could remove a selected item from my ListView of an image by this way:

```
private void Delte_Photo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewImage.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an image to be removed...");
                return;
            }

            ImageFileCollectionViewModel viewModel = ListViewImage.DataContext as ImageFileCollectionViewModel;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                ImageFileViewModel image = ListViewImage.SelectedItem as ImageFileViewModel;//ListViewImage is the listBox
                if (image != null)
                {
                    //remove physical file from disk:
                    File.Delete(image.FileName);
                    //remove item from ObservableCollection:
                    viewModel.AllImages.Remove(image);
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i remove multiple images?
How can i delete all the images? by button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your imagecollection via foreach

```
foreach(var image in viewModel.AllImages.ToList()){
    File.Delete(image.FileName);
    viewModel.AllImages.Remove(image);
}
```

to remove multiple instances at once:

```
        // let's say these are the positions of your items to remove
        var positions = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 6 };
        var list = viewModel.AllImages.ToList();

        // this removes all objects on the given index
        foreach (var position in positions)
        {
           list.RemoveAt(position);
        }
```

If you want to remove by objectreference iterate through a collection of objects to delete.

Comment: I'm getting this error:Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: I've found a solution that works for me. Call the `ToList()` of your `ObservableCollection<T>`. Tell me if it works.

Comment: :`var image in viewModel.AllImages.ToList()` it works. How can i remove multiple items? Thank you

Comment: :Could you please tell how can i remove it from the disk & observablecollection? Thank you.

Comment: Don't you remove it from disk with File.Delete and from Collection with .RemoveAt? Doesn't it work or do you want to do it in one step?

Comment: If i select one or multiple items by holding the control key then delete all the files from disk & ObCol!

Comment: You can access the selected items by `SelectedItems` property of `ListView`. After that you got the references.